# iphone - table with multiple selections

Tags: iphone

When you have multiple selections enabled for a table and select some cells, the selected cell have a red checkmark on the LEFT side. (see picture)  Don't mistake with the right side checkmark.

I have this in place

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Everything is fine. When I tap a cell a red check appears on the LEFT side.

At some point I have to iterate thru the table to discover which cells have this left checkmark.

As far as I tested this is not an accessoryType or a editingStyle. At least in my tests no cell could be detected as selected testing for these properties.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Is multiple selection in the API ? I thought it was only possible through subclassing

Comment: as I never used this functionality before, I don't know how it was then, but I see this on the docs for 4.x...

Comment: Can you give a link in the docs where it says you can use UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark for UITableViewCellEditingStyle?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html

Comment: That only shows the checkmark being used with accessoryType not as an editingStyle.  I think using it as an editingStyle is undocumented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned that it's not a good idea to rely on selections of cells. When a cell moves out of the view, the `UITableView` usually forgets about it. What I did was to create an `NSMutableArray` full of `BOOL` s and each time a cell is selected or deselected, I change the value at the right index. When I need the selected cells, I can simply use my array.

Comment: Thanks. You are right and the worst part of it is that it appears there's no way to test for that. Building an array did the trick.